# Difference in rotation of the atmosphere at different levels

Tags: angular-momentum, atmospheric-science

The atmosphere near ground level rotates at the same rate (on average) as the earth's surface because of drag effects beween air and ground, and continues to rotate because of inertia. Correct?

My question is about how the average rotation speed varies as we rise through and above the tropopause. I have read that the tropopause is nearly twice as high over the equator because of rotation, and I think that jetstreams are caused by coriolis plus solar heating differences. But is it possible to generalise about the rate of rotation at different altitudes? Any accessible sources on this, too?